# Node js (multer) req.file and req.files always undefined in react js but working fine with templating engines

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postman, multer

I'm trying to upload images to my server using Multer. If I use any **templating engine**, the **req.file** and **req.files** are **working fine**. But when I try to upload images with **postman or jsx form** in react, It returns **undefined**.

I'm using:
Multer - 1.4.2
Express - 4.17.1
Node - 14.16.1

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
//Routes Import
const data = require("./routes/router");

//Database Connection
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/newConnectSix", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
})
.then(console.log("connected!"));

//MiddleWares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//Route
app.use("/", data);

//Listening the port
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Listening to ${port}`);
});
```

**`multer.js`**

```
const multer = require("multer");

//set storage
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function (req, res, cb) {
 cb(null, "uploads");
 },
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  var ext = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));
  cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + ext);
},
});

module.exports = store = multer({ storage: storage });
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const store = require("../middleware/multer");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/uploadmultiple", store.array("images", 12), (req, res) => {
  const files = req.files;
  console.log(req.files);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**form.jsx**

```
<form
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  action="/uploadmultiple"
  encType="multipart/form-data"
  method="POST"
>
<label htmlFor="">Upload images:</label>
  <input
   name="images"
   type="file"
   className="form-control"
   multiple
   />
/>
```

**handleSubmit Function**

```
const apiEndpoint = "http://localhost:5000/uploadmultiple";

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
await axios.post(apiEndpoint);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking control of form submission with `onSubmit` and `e.preventDefault()`, but not sending the form with axios. You have two options:

1. Either remove the `onSubmit` handler and let the browser do the request for you:

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <form
         action="/uploadmultiple"
         encType="multipart/form-data"
         method="POST"
       >
       // ...
     );
   }
   ```
2. Or do the request yourself by constructing a form and sending it with axios:

   ```js
   const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();

     const form = new FormData();
     for (const file of e.target.files) {
       form.append('images', file);
     }

     await axios.post(apiEndpoint, form, {
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
       },
     });
   };
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response . I've tried it out and I'm getting this warning "Warning: Invalid DOM property `enctype`. Did you mean `encType`?" in react

Comment: Ah my bad, with React it's indeed `encType`. Can you edit your question to include the `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: Sure. Please check this out

Comment: @JahidHasan I've edit my answer. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the first solution you've mentioned and Now it's working... :)